# Flutter Hive putAt() cannot run if click done button on keyboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-hive

I try to make a flutter app using hive as a database.
There is a Container to show balance and if the user click the container a form dialog will show to change the balance value.
After change the value on TextFormField if user click submit everything will work fine, but if the user click the done button on the keyboard before click the submit button, the value will not change, but if user click on the container again and click the TextFormField the value suddenly change.

If I add hive putAt method in TextFormField onFieldSubmitted the value will change when user click the done button, but I want the value change when user click the submit button not the done button.

[GitHub Code](https://github.com/36Noya/hive_test)

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive_test/model/balance.dart';
import 'package:hive_test/ui/pages/main_page.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(BalanceAdapter());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

balance.dart

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'balance.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Balance {
  Balance({required this.value});
  @HiveField(0)
  int value;
}
```

balance.g.dart

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'balance.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class BalanceAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Balance> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  Balance read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Balance(
      value: fields[0] as int,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Balance obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.value);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is BalanceAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

main_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive_test/model/balance.dart';

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    Widget balance(balanceModel) {
      var balanceValue = balanceModel.getAt(0);
      TextEditingController balanceController =
          TextEditingController(text: balanceValue.value.toString());

      return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: Hive.box('balance').listenable(),
        builder: (context, box, widget) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        scrollable: true,
                        title: Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text('Jumlah'),
                        ),
                        content: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: Form(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: balanceController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Saldo',
                                icon: Icon(Icons.money_sharp),
                              ),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        actions: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: Text("Submit"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              balanceModel.putAt(
                                0,
                                Balance(
                                  value: int.parse(balanceController.text),
                                ),
                              );
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              fixedSize: Size(maxWidth * 9 / 10, 50),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Balance: ${balanceValue.value.toString()}',
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  fixedSize: Size(maxWidth * 9 / 10, 50),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Hive.openBox('balance'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  snapshot.error.toString(),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              var balanceModel = Hive.box('balance');
              if (balanceModel.length == 0) {
                balanceModel.add(Balance(value: 0));
              }

              return balance(balanceModel);
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Done Button

[image: Done Button]

Answer (score 0):

the keyboard **submit** is triggered with the `onSubmit` method property in the `TextFormField`, so instead of calling the `Hive.puAt()` in the `onPressed` property of `ElevatedButton`.

You need to make assign a `GlobalKey` to the `TextFomrField` then submit with from the `ElevatedButton`